# First build HelloWorld application not working

Tags: opendaylight

I'm newbie in Opendaylight. I'm trying the very first example of ODL controller application by following this tutorial:

[Controller Core Functionality Tutorials](https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/Controller_Core_Functionality_Tutorials:Application_Development_Tutorial#Exercise_3:_Implement_your_HelloWorld_RPC)

Of course it was not updated so I had to modify something for the newest version (Carbon SR3, on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS). However, when I executed the program, I couldn't find the message

> HelloProvider Session Initiated

by typing

> log:display | grep Hello

It means my application was not started. On the other hand, I verified features but there was only *odl-hello-api* by default (no *restconf, dlux, etc.*). I had to modified *karaf/pom.xml* (*karaf4-parent* version 3.0.2-SNAPSHOT, adding dependencies for *dlux-core* and *dluxapps*) to install these features but of course I coudln't find my application in ODL graphic application.

Anyone has the same issues? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The core tutorials project is no longer maintained. I would suggest looking at the toaster sample documented at https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Toaster_Step-By-Step. To try your own project, use the startup archetype documented at https://wiki.opendaylight.org/view/OpenDaylight_Controller:MD-SAL:Startup_Project_Archetype.

Comment: Configuration for the latest version to resolve my problems: _archetypeVersion=1.5.0-SNAPSHOT_, add manually to _karaf/pom.xml_ dependencies for features such as _odl-dlux-core_, _odl-dluxapps-yangui_ with _version=0.8.0-SNAPSHOT_. If not, there are so many bug for installation.